# NDK error with cstdlib

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, std

I am trying to build my first NDK library, and am getting an error when compiling:

> .../cstdlib:53: error: '::clearenv' has not been declared

Can I not use the C standard library with NDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by changing `<cstdlib>` to `<stdlib.h>`. Not sure why that worked, though.

Answer (score 0):

I too could solve it by changing `<cstdlib>` to `<stdlib.h>`.

I could also solve it by adding `APP_STL := <an stl lib>` to Application.mk

In any case, I have another NDK (r7) build where I have to do neither of these and it works.